# Google Sheets IMPORTXML for Price

Tags: google-sheets, scrape, price

I am trying to create a price scrape sheet in google sheets using the `IMPORTXML`function. I'm having trouble identifying the path for which the price on the product page.

I've tried copying the xPath using the inspect element in Chrome but it's copying the following: `//*[@id="ajaxPrice"]/span[2]`

I'm sure this is not the path.

Can someone please help?

Product page: https://homedepot.com/p/206651614

Answer (score 0):

How about this xpath?

```
=IMPORTXML(A1, "//span[@id='ajaxPrice']/@content")
```

- Cell "A1" has the URL of `https://homedepot.com/p/206651614`.

[image]

If this was not the result you want, I apologize. At that time, can you tell me about the value you want? I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I also need to do the same for 2 more sites. www.wayfair.com & www.amazon.com. The 206651614 in the HomeDepot link is an internal number for HomeDepot. How I generated that link, i just put the domain then "/" then product number (206651614). I am assuming that Wayfair and Amazon shorten their product links as well. The internal SKU for the exact same product for Wayfair is WLAO4144. I tried to type "www.wayfair.com/p/WLAO4144" The link is not valid. What is it that HomeDepot is doing? Is it some sort of link redirection or something

Comment: Thanks I will do that. But, do you know why I have a few cells that still have errors? The value still says "Loading...".

Comment: @nelson abeleda Thank you for cooperating to resolve your issue. About ``do you know why I have a few cells that still have errors?``, please do the following flow. 1. Create new Spreadsheet. 2. Put ``=IMPORTXML("https://homedepot.com/p/206651614", "//span[@id='ajaxPrice']/@content")`` to cell "A1". By this, if the error occurs, please share the Spreadsheet. If you want to use other URLs, the same xpath might not be able to be used. At that time, please check the xpath for each URL, if you want to use ``=IMPORTXML()``. About this, I apologize that I don't know about other URLs you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this too:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 IMPORTDATA("https://homedepot.com/p/206651614"), 1500, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'ciItemPrice'"), "\d+.\d+|\d+")
```

[image: 0]